# Degree of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I am struggling to solve these two problems in Galois Theory. Could you help me please?

---

Suppose $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3}, \sqrt[5]{7})$

> Prove that $[K : \mathbb{Q}]=25$

$K$ is a splitting field of the polynomial $(x^5-3)(x^5-7)$

Must consider $K$ as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

> Find all subfields $L \subset K$ such that $[L : \mathbb{Q}]=5$

Due to Galois correspondence, we can consider subgroups of $G=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ of order $5$

What are the elements in $G$ of order $5$?

I need to first analyse the structure of $G$ and find the automorphisms which generate the group, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: $K$ cannot be the splitting field as it doesnt contain the 5th roots of unity

Comment: @MattB what would be the best way to approach this question?

Comment: I would suggest moving to the splitting field $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5,\sqrt[5]{3},\sqrt[5]{7})$, figure out what subgroup $H$ of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ fixes $K$ and then look at the fixed field of all subgroups of $H$ of suitable index which should correspond to the intermediate fields.